# Which is the more correct page layout?

Tags: html

With the addition of the `<main>` element in the HTML5 draft spec, which is the more correct page layout?

```
<body>
    <header> ... </header>
    <main>
        <aside> ... </aside>
    </main>
    <footer> ... </footer>
</body>
```

or;

```
<body>
    <header> ... </header>
    <section>
        <main> ... </main>
        <aside> ... </aside>
    </section>
    <footer> ... </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't it a little too early to ask? Some searching on my part reveals the HTML5.1 spec, and... an extension spec?

Comment: Both html5shiv and normalize.css have thrown their weight behind it by  including it in their code, so I'd say the expectation is that people are going to start using it

Comment: Also all major browsers added the support already.

Comment: And which spec are the browsers following? The question of which is more semantically correct is dependent on what is stated in a much newer and less stable document, and it's not clear to me *which* document is the right one.

Comment: The most informative articles I have found are the [use case](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/User:Sfaulkne/main-usecases) by David Faulkner (the author of the extension spec) and [this article](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/01/html5/the-main-element) by Ian Devlin. Neither really address where the sidebar should go.

Comment: @darronz make that "steve faulkner" :-)

Comment: @BoltClock Info about the relationship between the extension spec and HTML 5.1 is here: https://twitter.com/robinberjon/status/289716478004060160

Comment: @SteveFaulkner whoops! Sorry Steve, and thank you for your answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer as to the correctness of each of the example markup patterns can be found in the [normative definition](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) of the main element.

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>   Where flow content is expected, but with no article, aside, footer,
>   header or nav element ancestors.
>   Authors must not include more than one main element in a document.

In this case either example markup is conforming. It is difficult to know which is the most appropriate or practical from a theoretical example alone.

> And which spec are the browsers following?

Browsers have implemented the main element as defined in the [W3C HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html). Conformance checkers such as the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) will implement the conformance requirements of the W3C HTML spec.

**Note:** The main element will be [added to HTML 5.0](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Jan/0205.html) in the near future.

**Note:** The specification of the main element in HTML 5.1 supersedes the extension spec.

Comment: Thanks for answering my comment! Now I understand the relationship between HTML 5.0, 5.1, and the extension spec, in particular w.r.t. the `main` element and implementations thereof.

Answer (score 2):

As always it depends on the content.

For me, if the contents of the `header` and `footer` are generic to all pages, then leave them outside of the `main` element whose content should be specific to that page. If, however, the `header` and/or `footer` are relevant to the main contents of that page only, then put them inside the `main`.

The same logic applies to the `aside` element.

Plus read what Steve Faulkner says on this page. He knows everything!

**Update!**
Due to this particular question, I have posted an [article](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/02/html5/further-examples-on-using-the-main-element) with further examples on how the `main` element might be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you have placed <main> within a <section>.

Since <body> is implicitly a "section" and the <section> belongs to it, the <section> is - in fact - a subsection.

This causes a problem.

Why?

As Steve points out, you can only use <main> once per page. In this example, you have chosen to use the one element that defines the *main* part of the page within a subsection of that page.

The "main" part of something surely cannot belong to a subset of that thing. This simply doesn't make sense, regardless of what you are "allowed" to do according to the current specification. Your deployment of <main>, in this example, is at odds with the structural intent described by your use of sectioning content.

In structural terms, the first example is - therefore - slightly superior, although your *semantic* choice of <aside> is suboptimal. You've essentially said, "here is the most important part of my page's content and in it is some tangential, loosely related stuff". Tangential to what?

Unless...

you are intending to put some flow content directly within the <main> region, adjacent to the <aside>. This content would belong directly to main, which belongs directly to <body>. The <aside> remains a subsection of <body> and is actually an "aside" to some main content.

This would be totally sound.

Comment: please file a bug against the spec if you think that main should not be allowed in <section>

Comment: Has a bug been filed for this? The logic Heydon lays out makes sense to me that the main element should not be inside a section element.